# Install Catalyst 12.1 Driver makes system Slower

Tags: 11.10, drivers, ati, radeon, catalyst

I'm using a Toshiba Satellite T135D with GPU Radeon Mobility HD 3200

I've installed latest driver catalyst from AMD and why the graphics performance of my laptop become slower than previous?
My step

1. Download and install the driver
2. sudo aticonfig --inital -f
3. Turn off Vscync and change the refresh rate in CCSM, but the performance still laggy T_T

Comment: you really should just wait for it to be shipped with jockey and use that to manage all your proprietary drivers

Comment: Uhm.. the drivers for the GPUs get updated in the official repos? I thought they froze the software and didn't update unless necessary

Answer (score 0):

With your GPU, best would be to switch to Unity 2d.